# upon DidSelect, how to return whole core data record? (swift)

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I can access the properties of the core data record upon select, but not the whole record. I want the whole thing so I can store it as a variable, then save another entity with a relationship to this one. Only thing I can think of is to trigger another fetch with a narrow predicate - but that can't be the way..can it?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        if (tableView == tableViewTeams) {
            let currentTeam = teamResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Teams
            forwardResultController = forwardResultControllerFunc(myQuery: currentTeam.teamName)
            forwardResultController.delegate = self
            forwardResultController.performFetch(nil)
            defenderResultController = defenderResultControllerFunc(myTeam: currentTeam.teamName)
            defenderResultController.delegate = self
            defenderResultController.performFetch(nil)
            tableView1.reloadData()
            tableView2.reloadData()
        }
//…other tableviews
}

    func createPlayer() {
        let playerEntityDescripition = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Players", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
        let player = Players(entity: playerEntityDescripition!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        let teamDict:NSDictionary = selectedTeam.lastObject as NSDictionary
        var teamID = teamDict.objectForKey("teamName") as String
        let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "teamName == '\(teamID)'")!
        let results:NSArray = SwiftCoreDataHelper.fetchEntities(NSStringFromClass(Teams), withPredicate: predicate, managedObjectContext: moc)
        let currentTeam:Teams = results.lastObject as Teams
        player.firstName = playerFirstName.text
        player.lastName = playerLastName.text
        player.type = playerPosition.text
        player.number = playerNumber.text
        player.team = currentTeam
        managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
    }

//one of the fetch requests
    func fetchRequest(#myQuery: String, myQuery2: String, myQuery3: String) -> NSFetchRequest {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Players")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)
        let filter = NSPredicate(format: "team.teamName = %@ AND (type = %@ OR type = %@ )", "\(myQuery)", "\(myQuery2)", "\(myQuery3)")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.predicate = filter
        println(filter!)
        return fetchRequest
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity for a team is called `Teams` in the plural. Why? Confusing.
The same goes for your entity `Players`.

In your code, you are writing a function inside a function. (The bracket for `didSelectRow` never closes.) Why? Confusing.

If you want to create a player when a team is selected from the teams table, just make sure the variables you need are in the same *scope*. If you have one method where you define `currentTeam` it will not be known in another method.

You could simply change your `createPlayer()` method to return the player (add `-> Player` to the signature and return the player at the end with `return player`) and call that from the table selection callback.

```
var newPlayer = createPlayer()
newPlayer.team = currentTeam
```

Comment: sorry I forgot the curly brackets - see edit above for an update. The naming convention is because I've never used a DB via an abstraction layer - no matter how many times I read that entities are not tables...old habits die hard. I had a heck of a time getting this working, and actually ended up doing a fetch request for a string, then searching again to feed it to the other function. In the create player function it wouldn't let me just define player.team as a managedobjectwithID from the other entity.

Comment: You should accept the answer. It shows how you can link your team-player relationship.

Comment: Sort of. I think what I really want to do is return the team from the DidSelect function, then feed that to the create player function. You're right on both counts though: this is how to get NSMObjects out of a function and I should accept the answer.